# Fastest way to copy/paste(reinstall) all Nuget Packages from one project to another?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I have a .csproj named **"A"** with many Nuget packages.

I want to create a similar .csproj named **"B"**, with the same Nuget packages of "A".

In the same solution, I also have others .csproj with other stuff.

What's the fastest way to do it?

I tried to copy the packages.config from one to another and then executed this:

```
Update-Package –reinstall
```

The result was that it reinstalled ALL packages of ALL projects, but didn't really created any file on project **"B"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just missed one switch.  What if you copy the packages.config, as you did, and then use

Update-Package -reinstall -**ProjectName (TheProjectName)**

Comment: is this syntax correct? I'm getting an error: "Update-Package : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name '<MyProject>'"

Comment: oh, I only needed to change this part: "(TheProjectName)" of your command. I was confused. Thanks!!!

Comment: It worked for me -- using Visual Studio 2015 --  I tested before I replied.  Here is the exact line that I used inside of the PackageManager console in vs: update-package -ProjectName ClassLibrary1 -Reinstall